# If I extend a segment AB, how do I find its new coordinates?

Tags: geometry

I want to extend any given segment for which I know the x-y coordinates for its extremities A and B.
Say I have the AB segment in the picture below, and now I want to increase its length (with a known length) so I drag B and move it to a new position farther away. (not changing the orientation of the segment just elongate it on the same direction)

Is there a way to know the new x and y of B please?

[image]

**Edit:** Thanks guys for all your answers.
I don't know which one is correct as I don't fully understand them yet. I will implement them programmatically and see how it works and will update here.
Thanks again!

Comment: Do you know the length of the extension, or equivalently the length of the new full size segment? If so, then you can use the slope, with the exception of when the segment is vertical (but of course when the segment is either vertical or horizontal, the situation is easy).

Comment: @ian yes I know the full segment length. How can I use the slope, please? Make a right triangle and find the cathetus?

Answer (score 1):

Call $x_M,y_M$ the coordinates of a point $M=A,B,$ and your new endpoint $B',$ and $k=\frac{AB'}{AB}.$ Then,

$x_{B'}=x_A+k(x_B-x_A)$ and $y_{B'}=y_A+k(y_B-y_A)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(x_1,y_1)$ and $B=(x_2,y_2)$.  Note that
$$
y_2-y_1=m(x_2-x_1)
$$
and
$$
d^2=(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2
$$
Hence
$$
d^2=(x_2-x_1)^2+m^2(x_2-x_1)^2
$$
and
$$
x_2=x_1\pm\dfrac{d}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$
Of course
$$
y_2=y_1+m(x_2-x_1)
$$
and hence
$$
y_2=y_1\pm\dfrac{dm}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$
Hence the coordinates are:
$$
(x_2,y_2)=\left(x_1\pm\dfrac{d}{\sqrt{1+m^2}},y_1\pm\dfrac{dm}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\right)
$$
However, if you are wanting some kind of "drag" operation in desmos for instance, you don't actually need $y_2$.  So, you could write:
$$
y-y_{1}=m\left(x-x_{1}\right)\left\{\min\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)<x<\max\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)\right\}
$$
$$
x_2=x_1+\dfrac{dm}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}
$$
and then add sliders for $x_1$, $y_1$, $m$, and $d$.  (Note that if you do this then $d$ becomes a "signed" distance depending on whether $B$ is left or right of $A$.)

Answer (score 1):

HINT

It depends on how much you drag. The straight line equation is

$$ m=\dfrac{y_B-y_A}{x_B-x_A}=\dfrac{\text{draggedlength~y~ projection}}{\text{draggedlength~x~projection}}$$

where $m$ is its slope.